# How many branches are fetched after git fetch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

Assuming I have tracking branch br1 and I am on that branch will git fetch downloand changes only for that branch or every other branch from the same remote as br1.

Comment: Note that `git fetch` fetches *their* branch or branches, not *your* branch or branches. You might have a `br1` with upstream `origin/br1`; they might have a `br1` too; but their `br1` is your *`origin/br1`* (your remote-tracking name) which is not a *branch*. Your *branch* is your `br1`, and `git fetch` does not touch it.

Comment: This means that if you run `git fetch` by itself, all of your `origin/*` names get updated, but none of **your** *branches* are touched at all. If you run `git fetch origin br1`, your `origin/br1` is updated, but again, none of your branches are touched at all. Fetch obtains commits and updates your *remote-tracking names*.

Comment: To put it another way: your branches are **yours**, their branches are **theirs**, and the two are different. Your remote-tracking names exist so that `git fetch` can copy their branches into your repository safely, at any time. If you want the result to affect your branch(es), you need to run additional Git commands.

Answer (score 3):

`git fetch` fetch all changes of the branches from the repository.

`git fetch <remote> <branch>` only fetch the specified branch.

Documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch

`git fetch` only downloads the data to your local repository — it doesn’t automatically merge it with any of your work or modify what you’re currently working on. You have to merge it manually into your work when you’re ready